# UWP build error : Internal compiler error: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: .net, msbuild, uwp

Hard to find the problem, but my uwp app cannot make app package due to *Internal compiler error: Index was outside the bounds of the array* error occurred.

The strange thing is that,

- It can build and run by *unchecking* `Compile with .NET Native tool chain` in Project Properties.
- There's nowhere referencing `EntityFramework` bits. why the error message pointing that?

Is the `Compile with .NET Native tool chain` feature has malfunction?

The error message is as below.

> 1>------ Build started: Project: SampleUwpApp, Configuration: Release x86 ------
>   1>  Sample.App -> C:\Users\Me\Documents\SampleProject\SampleUwpApp\bin\x86\Release\SampleUwpApp.exe
>   1>  Starting .NET Native compilation
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1592,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1592,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1592,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1912,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1912,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1912,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Console, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1912,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1912,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1912,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Xml.XPath, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1936,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1936,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1936,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Console, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1936,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1936,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(1936,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Xml.XPath, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>  Processing application code
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(601,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(601,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(601,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Console, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(601,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(601,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(601,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Xml.XPath, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(601,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(601,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(601,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Console, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(601,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(601,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(601,5): warning : ILTransform_0010: Could not find assembly 'System.Xml.XPath, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by 'EntityFramework'.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : Internal compiler error: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: What version of MS Build (or Visual Studio) are you using? Have you applied the latest updates?

Comment: @IInspectable // I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 2 and 3 (both cases in different PC). Targeting minimum 10240 and Target 10586.

Comment: Check if you have any references that are not being used by your app and remove them.

Comment: Found a problem, I use reference PCL project for model classes and it references EntityFramework 6.4.1 for DataAnnotation. However, currently, migrate to EF core and .Net Standard 1.4 does not solve the problem. Let me post answer when I solve the issue.